# Spark dataframe add a row for every existing row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have a dataframe with following columns:

```
groupid,unit,height
----------------------
1,in,55
2,in,54
```

I want to create another dataframe with additional rows where unit=cm and height=height*2.54.

**Resulting dataframe**:

```
groupid,unit,height
----------------------
1,in,55
2,in,54
1,cm,139.7
2,cm,137.16
```

Not sure how I can use spark udf and explode here.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can create another `dataframe` with changes you require using `withColumn` and then `union` both `dataframes` as

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "in", 55),
  (2, "in", 54)
).toDF("groupid", "unit", "height")

val df2 = df.withColumn("unit", lit("cm")).withColumn("height", col("height")*2.54)

df.union(df2).show(false)
```

you should have

```
+-------+----+------+
|groupid|unit|height|
+-------+----+------+
|1      |in  |55.0  |
|2      |in  |54.0  |
|1      |cm  |139.7 |
|2      |cm  |137.16|
+-------+----+------+
```